# Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument , when calling the function

Tags: r

I have tried the multiple ways to solve it but I'm out of ideas. Here is my code:

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332){
        filelist <- list.files(path = "directory", pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)
        value <- data.frame()
        
        for (i in id) {
                dat <- read.csv(filelist[i], header = TRUE)
                value <- rbind(value, dat[[pollutant]])
                
        }
        mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

error I'm getting when calling the function is:

```
pollutantmean("specdata", 'sulfate', 1:10)
Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument
```

I don't know what the error is I have also tried `traceback()`:

```
4.file(file, "rt") 

3.read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
       dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...) 

2.read.csv(filelist[i], header = TRUE) at pollutantmean.R#6

1.pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 1:10)
```

[image]

Comment: Typo? `for (i in sq(id))` should be `seq`.

Comment: still, it's showing the same error

Comment: OK, another typo, `list.files(path <- "directory"` should be `list.files(path = directory`

Comment: will that give a difference in R because in R <- is also = right

Comment: No, they are not the same. When assigning a function argument only `=` is valid. `path <- directory` will create a variable `path`, assign it the value `directory` and pass it as the function's first argument.

Comment: I would try `for (i in seq_along(id))`. And in `list.files(path = directory, pattern = "\\.csv")` with the double `\\\` to escape the dot meta-character.

Comment: I have tried as u said again showing the error

Comment: You are still using `"directory"`. This is a string, **not** the function argument `directory`. Remove the quotes. And note that `value` is a data.frame when you obviously want a vector of pollutant values. Before the loop, do `value <- NULL` and inside, `value <- c(value, dat[[pollutant]])`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, the following code could work.

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332){
  filelist <- list.files(path = directory, pattern = "\\.csv", full.names = TRUE)
  i <- seq(1, min(length(filelist), length(id)))
  value <- lapply(filelist[i], read.csv)
  value <- sapply(value, '[[', pollutant)
  mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: thanks taking your time out and writing code for me, but, it returns the same error

Comment: @pratappudi Try `dir.exists(your_dir)` and `list.files(path = your_path, pattern = '\\.csv')` and see what they both return.

Answer (score 0):

```
        > dir.exists("~/R/Air Pollution Data - US/Data/specdata/")
        [1] TRUE
        > list.files(list.files(path = ~/R/Air Pollution Data - US/Data/specdata/, 
        pattern = '\\.csv'))
        Error: unexpected '/' in "list.files(list.files(path = ~/"
        > list.files(list.files(path = "~/R/Air Pollution Data - US/Data/specdata/", 
        pattern = '\\.csv'))
        character(0)
```

Result I'm getting